# Can $f\in W^{k,p}(U)$ be extended to a function in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in general?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $f\in L^p(U)$ for some $p$ with $1\leq p<\infty$. By extending $f$ to be identically zero outside $U$, one has $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

My **question** is: if one replaces $L^p$ with $W^{k,p}$ ($k\geq 1$), is the statement above still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just choose the function to be identically zero outside $U$ in general, because this can cause the weak derivative to fail to be $L^p$ because of "bad regularity" at the boundary. For instance when $n=1$, all $W^{k,p}$ functions are actually continuous, so extending $f(x)=1$ on $(0,1)$ to be identically zero elsewhere certainly does not give a $W^{k,p}$ function. In this case the weak derivative is a delta function, which is not an $L^p$ function.

That said, a $W^{k,p}$ extension exists for certain "nice" $U$. For instance cf. Theorem 4.3 in the notes https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/sobolev-notes.pdf

Comment: One the other hand, if the boundary is ignored, one would get $f\in W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\partial U)$, right?

Comment: @Jack Sure, it's piecewise constant, compactly supported, and the regions with the two constants are distinct connected components. But Sobolev spaces defined on disconnected domains are not of all that much use.

Answer (score 0):

It's false. For a counterexample consider $n = k = p = 1$, $U = (0,1)$ and $f \equiv 1$.

It is possible to extend Sobolev functions under certain regularity assumptions on the boundary of the set $U$, but it is delicate. Any book on Sobolev spaces addresses the issue.